# Process the jms messages sequentially/concurrently?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

My JMS consumer produces any number(Say n) of messages on JMS queue during the day. First I am evaluating the synchronous processing of message

Say at 23.0 clock,  now I want to consume all messages. Here is main method

**Here's how to do it sequentially(not concurrently) :-**

Do I need to call consumer.receive() method n times (till returns consumer.receive() return null )on single consumer?

```
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
             // Create a Connection
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            // Create a Session
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
            Destination destination = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");

            // Create a MessageConsumer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

            // Wait for a message
            Message message = consumer.receive();
```

**How to do it concurrently :- I want to process the 20 messages concurrently**

Do I need to create 20 thread where each thread creates its own consumer and the receive the message?

Comment: Have you tried your own suggestions?

Comment: @Simon first one i tried but about second one i am not sure if it is right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process 20 messages sequentially, and you know you will receive at least 20 messages, put the `MessageConsumer.receive()` call into a loop 20 times.   Note that `MessageConsumer.receive()` without a timeout argument will not return null if there are no messages on the queue.  It will block until it receives a message, or until `close()` is called.  If you use `MessageConsumer.receive(longTimeoutValue)`, it will wait for longTimeoutValue to receive a message, and will return null if no message is received by then.

For concurrent message processing, the ActiveMQ docs provide a sample of how to use multiple consumers here: http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html, which you can modify for your purposes.  The sample creates a new connection per thread, but according to  http://activemq.apache.org/multiple-consumers-on-a-queue.html, you are only required to create a session and consumer per thread.

Comment: @Ireeder As i said in my post that "each thread creates its own consumer " not a single consumer. So looks like i am not right path?

Comment: Each thread should create its own consumer, but it should also create it a separate session for each consumer.

Comment: @Ireeder what about my first question where i am doing it sequentially. In that case i can use same consumer , just need to call receive multiple times. Right?

Comment: I missed that part of your question. My answer has been updated, but yes, basically just call receive multiple times as you expect.

Comment: @ireeder. Cam you provide insight on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890086/how-to-concurrently-process-the-asynchronous-jms-queue-message. Thanks in advance.