# How to concurrently process the asynchronous jms queue message?

Tags: java, jms

My JMS consumer produces any number of messages on a JMS queue during the day. As soon as a
message arrives it goes to message listener. If in between I need some other message comes, it goes to another message listener does not wait for first one?

As per my understanding here I need to  create two consumer(assume i want to process 2 message concurrently) each having its own session. Both consumer can use the same message listener. Right?

I am not sure if I can achieve it with single consumer but can I with multiple listeners?

something like this [Single queue: concurrent message processing with multiple consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078801/single-queue-concurrent-message-processing-with-multiple-consumers)

Comment: If you have a consumer that is not context reliant you could instantiate one consumer and n listeners on threads that execute a single instance of the inantiated consumer. You'd need to make sure you code is thread safe though ... just a thought.

Comment: What is the difference between a consumer and a "message listener"?

Comment: Please check the docs.. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncep/index.html

Comment: @lreeder  is my understanding correct. We have to create two consumer with separate session. Can do it with single consumer but with two sparate listener. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [JMS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncep/index.html) @bgth cites, multiple MessageListeners in a single session will not provide concurrency:

"The session used to create the message consumer serializes the execution of all message listeners registered with the session. **At any time, only one of the session’s message listeners is running**"

For concurrency, you need multiple sessions and multiple consumers in separate threads.   You can reuse the same MessageListener in this case, but it must be threadsafe.